# How to use triggered restart with sbt-revolver under IntelliJ IDEA 14?

Tags: sbt, spray, intellij-14

Following the [spray template project](https://github.com/spray/spray-template/blob/on_spray-can_1.3/project/plugins.sbt), I've put the following sbt plugin definition into my IntelliJ 14 SBT based Scala project in `project/plugins.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.7.1")
```

Added `Resvlver.settings` to `build.sbt` (as per spray template [build.sbt](https://github.com/spray/spray-template/blob/on_spray-can_1.3/build.sbt) file). It is still highlighted in red, but does not fail.

Now I want to have [the triggered-restart feature of sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) working. Where and how do I add the `~re-start` argument in IDEA?

Comment: If you want the RED to disappear try this (instead of: Resvlver.settings):
Revolver.settings: Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]]

Did you make the hot reload to work? I also have the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** You can't in IDEA 14.0.1 and earlier. I heard no plans about such support.